# A hybrid boot for linux on external drive?

Tags: multi-boot, grub, uefi, arch-linux

I have installed Arch on my external SSD working in UEFI mode. But I am not getting the very advantage of portability because of many systems running on legacy mode and hence not supporting my UEFI based Linux.

So is there a way where I can create a hybrid boot, that can work on any system? Basically like creating a new MBR boot partition?

A bit simple language will be highly appreciated.

[image: current partition]

Comment: You can run `grub-install` multiple times with different `--target` specified. However to install the BIOS (`i386-pc`) variant on a drive with GPT, you'll need an extra unformatted "BIOS boot partition". Refer to the ArchWiki for details.

Comment: @TomYan I created an unformatted partition. Set the flag to grub_bios as said in ArchWiki. Ran grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sd on the drive. and then created config file.
Now the dev/sdb7 is showing "grub2core.img " in gparted. Tried it in a legacy dystem. Not getting detected. Did i miss something?

Comment: Why are folks enabling [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting)? **CSM Mode is _solely_ for distros that didn't support EFI boot _circa <2017_** - all OSes support EFI boot, so disable CSM Mode, convert the OS disk to GPT, and modify partitions accordingly with the correct GUIDs. UEFI is 64bit and CSM Mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment - doing so causes performance degradation _(boot times increase by 400%+, GPT can't be used, etc.)_ Only purpose for CSM mode now is when needing to access a legacy OP ROM